# Add :before content to an elements child

Tags: css, css-selectors, pseudo-element

I have the following, simplified:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="button-1">
    <a href="somewhere">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The 'a' is dynamically loaded and I cannot add a class to it. I can only add a class to the 'li'. I want to add an icon before the 'a', so that it is included as part of the clickable link.

Currently I have:

```
.button-1:before {
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f007";
    padding-left: 14px;
}
```

which sets the icon perfectly above the text link. But it's not clickable. Thus, I tried...

```
.button-1 a:before
```

But this doesn't work. Nor any other variation that I can think of or find. I think I am being incredibly stupid here and missing something obvious. Any advice. Thanks

Comment: There is no `.button` class in your HTML. It's `.button-1`.

Comment: The fontawesome icon is clickable for me ( currently on an iPad using Safari) but it is not underlined.

Comment: Apologies - in simplifying the code I inadvertently got the class names wrong. Assume they are correct and both "button". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works (i.e. clickable etc.) when you use the `:before` on the child, i.e. `.button-1 > a:before`:

```css
.button-1 > a:before {
    content: "© ";
    
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="button-1">
    <a href="somewhere">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

(As you can see, I used some other content to work around the non-available FontAwesome Icon)

ADDITION AFER COMMENTS:

You can also use `:afer` insteadof `before`. In this case you need some more settings, also for the parent, especially a relative/absolute position pairing as shown below:

```css
.button-1 {
  position: relative;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.button-1>a:after {
  content: "©";
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li class="button-1">
    <a href="somewhere">Link</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: It seems to work without the parent needed in the selector, but if it is a fontawesome icon it is not underlined but it is clickable.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean (?)

Comment: Thanks Johannes. I tried that already though and it doesn't work. I don't understand why. Using Chrome 87.0.4280.141

Comment: I think I understand now. As the 'a' is dynamically loaded, the element doesn't exist when it's trying to add the 'before'. But, if I change it to 'after', it works. So now, I can get it to show, but I need to make it appear before the A, rather than after. If that makes sense.

Comment: It's possible also using `:after`- have a look at what I added to my answer.

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to make the two stacked, one on top of each other? So that the 'icon' appears above the text. All contained within the link?

Comment: well, try it: Use a different setting for `left`(maybe also a percentage value), add a *negative* `top` setting and a `padding-top` for `button-1` and adjust these values until you find a satisfying solution.

Comment: Thanks Johannes. You've been a great help. Appreciate your time.

Comment: Concerning my next-to-last comment re moving the icon above the text, you won't need *negative*  `top` values since the vertical reference for `top` is the (invisible) border * above*  the `padding-top`. Just try around a bit with different values and you'll find what works well.